# Downgrade tomcat 8.5.16 to tomcat 8.0.46 in AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum, tomcat

due to incompatibility (cookies related) I would like to downgrade tomcat 8.5.16 to tomcat 8.0.46 in my AWS AMI. Amazon just automatically updated it in the past day.

I tried the following but without success:

```
[root@xxx ec2-user]# sudo yum downgrade tomcat8

Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
36 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Nothing to do
```

I do not want to undo the whole

```
yum history undo <id number>
```

Is there another alternative?

BTW, my machine is:

```
[root@ip-xxxx ec2-user]# uname -a

Linux ip-xxxx 4.9.51-10.52.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 29 01:16:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `sudo yum remove tomcat8` then install the version you want?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon documented in the [release notes](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2017.09-release-notes/):

```
Known issues
Since we've moved from tomcat 8 to tomcat 8.5, there may be a few minor backwards incompatibilities.
```

For me the minor incompatibility is that I cannot log in to my app anymore.

They don't make it so easy to go back... but you can.

```
sudo vim /etc/yum.conf
```

Make this change:

```
#releasever=latest
releasever=2017.03
```

Then you're able to downgrade using yum:

```
sudo yum downgrade tomcat8 tomcat8-admin-webapps tomcat8-lib tomcat8-servlet-3.1-api tomcat8-el-3.0-api tomcat8-jsp-2.3-api
```

yum's somewhat verbose output confirms what will happen:

```
...
---> Package tomcat8.noarch 0:8.0.46-1.76.amzn1 will be a downgrade
---> Package tomcat8.noarch 0:8.5.16-1.74.amzn1 will be erased
---> Package tomcat8-admin-webapps.noarch 0:8.0.46-1.76.amzn1 will be a downgrade
---> Package tomcat8-admin-webapps.noarch 0:8.5.16-1.74.amzn1 will be erased
---> Package tomcat8-el-3.0-api.noarch 0:8.0.46-1.76.amzn1 will be a downgrade
---> Package tomcat8-el-3.0-api.noarch 0:8.5.16-1.74.amzn1 will be erased
---> Package tomcat8-jsp-2.3-api.noarch 0:8.0.46-1.76.amzn1 will be a downgrade
---> Package tomcat8-jsp-2.3-api.noarch 0:8.5.16-1.74.amzn1 will be erased
---> Package tomcat8-lib.noarch 0:8.0.46-1.76.amzn1 will be a downgrade
---> Package tomcat8-lib.noarch 0:8.5.16-1.74.amzn1 will be erased
---> Package tomcat8-servlet-3.1-api.noarch 0:8.0.46-1.76.amzn1 will be a downgrade
---> Package tomcat8-servlet-3.1-api.noarch 0:8.5.16-1.74.amzn1 will be erased
...
```

Happy happy. I'm looking forward to Tomcat 8.5 someday soon. But not today.

Comment: FYI: other folks are unlikely to re-encounter this problem. Now that I'm ready for tomcat85 I finally updated using yum. But now Amazon has tweaked things so tomcat8.noarch 8.0.46-1.76.amzn1 is replaced by tomcat80.noarch.8.0.47-1.78.amzn1 (note the "80" rather than just "8"). Updating to tomcat85 will have to be done explicitly. I like this change; I only wish they had started this way.